# which one is the best windows program loader for Ubuntu11.10?

Tags: 11.10, wine

I want to install windows program loader but I still confuse to choose which one is compatible for my Ubuntu 11.10.Which is you all recomended Wine or Play on linux??

Thankyou for your time

Answer (score 1):

Play on linux is like a frontend to wine. It will select the best wine version for your apps. (I prefer Play on Linux)

Comment: wine can browse c: can play on linux do the same thing?

Comment: www.playonlinux.com/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayOnLinux
The "Browse drive c:" is for wine installed apps. Wine creates a windows like environment in your home folder. It is not the windows drive. As PlayOnLinux is a frontend to wine, it is superior.